# Can I replace the entire hose bib stem?

Tags: plumbing

Your info on replacing hose bib washer was very helpful.  Can I replace the entire stem arrangement along with the handle.  My hose bibb is probably from 1981 and very corroded.  I tried HD and Lowes they do not handle the stem.  Local Plumbing supply just carries the washers.  Please advise where I can locate the entire stem if it is possible to replace.

Answer (score 1):

The way you get a new stem is to get a whole new sillcock/hose bibb.

If the stem is that corroded, the body probably is as well, so it's likely to not seal right even if you could fine one to match a specific 34 year old valve body (which seems like a bit of a stretch.)

If you can identify your particular valve you MIGHT find a specialist "repair parts" plumbing supplier that has parts, such as (maybe) this one; http://www.azpartsmaster.com/faucet-valve-stem.aspx but if you cannot positively identify the valve, that's unlikely to work (and if the body itself is bad, it may not work anyway, as already mentioned.) If you need a place you can walk into with a valve stem you may need to take a LONG drive to find one "near" you that goes beyond just washers.

At some point fairly early in the process (IMHO) replacing the whole valve makes more sense.

Comment: I concur with @Ecnerwal, finding a replacement stem is 99.999% unlikely. You should mentally prepare yourself for a valve replacement job.

Comment: thank you both very much for the responses.....I was afraid of the outcome.....will have to step back on reconsider.  Thanks again, pbl

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the whole thing. Go in the crawl space and if it's like 99.9% of any hose bibb, it's on a copper male adaptor. You hold back on the male adaptor with a pair of channel locks and spin the bibb off with another pair. Tape and dope the male adaptor and send a new one in. The common sizes are 4,6 & 8". Just buy all three and return the other two. To make sure it's straight, use a magic marker and mark the bottom before you send it in. Anything more than that, call a plumber. Rebuilding them only means you will put a brand new washer onto a scarred up seat. It will leak again in a few weeks. Rebuilding hose bibbs is for handymen and janitors