# Need help identifying sillcock valve manufacturer / model

Tags: plumbing

I want to replace the stem of a frost-free (sillcock) valve; it appears to be 6in. I don't want to replace the whole thing, as it is in a difficult-to-access place. The valve wast installed about 15 yrs ago; I could not identify it by searching google images. The far end of the stem is not round; it appears vaguely triangular.

I am attaching my photos.
[image: The stem]
[image: Valve body]

I could not find any markings anywhere on the stem; the body of the valve has the UPC mark and characters L.T. above. The backflow protector is B.K. / Mueller, but I am not sure the rest is by Mueller as their sillcock stems (that I could find pictures of) look different.

Any advice on who might be the manufacturer of the valve would be much appreciated.

Dmitri

Comment: See this question (at least your sillcock is a bit more recent) and answers for some related info and at least one *possible* parts source (which might have some identification help as well, not sure) http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68933/can-i-replace-the-entire-hose-bib-stem/68946#68946

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Thanks! I sent a message to AZ Partsmaster. On the website I could only find stems for "regular" faucets (not frost-free "remote" ones), but certainly they are a reasonable place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told that this is an old B.K., made in China and no longer manufactured, available until about a couple years ago (this would be around 2012-2013)